# Rotate webpage via code?

Tags: javascript, css, svg, css-transforms

I'm hoping that there's a relatively simple way to rotate a webpage a little bit, 30 degrees or so, while still leaving it fully functional and usable.

I completely control the page, and can modify it to make this easier if needed.  I'd rather not re-write the whole thing in SVG, though, but perhaps javascript and canvas will work?

Is there a way using CSS, Javascript, or some other cross browser method that would allow me to accomplish this?

Comment: For the inevitable "Why?!", April fools day is not far off, and my customers can use a little humor in their day.

Comment: utterly useless +1

Comment: You should really ask the browser this question, not us on SO. It's the browser that interprets HTML and renders an image, not us.

Comment: This question really made my day.  I'm going to have to use it for April 1st as well, if you don't mind.

Comment: 180 degrees sound more fun ;)

Comment: I get all kinds of requests like these (i work in online advertisment & rich media). I can see this could be cool if used properly.

Comment: Tipping feature request - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36567/how-come-no-option-to-tip-answerers

Comment: This question and both answers are made of EPIC. (I actually can see legitimate uses for these, primarily in effects like scattered photos, etc.)

Comment: If anyone has other revelation-type css stuff like this that they've come across in stack overflow questions, I'd love to hear 'bout 'em, not to hijack from the original poster...

Comment: @Adam: answer has been added, comment removed.

Comment: Definitely cross browser is a server-side solution as showcased on http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pete/upside-down-ternet.html .

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Here's another solution based on the matrix filter which works in IE.

http://www.boogdesign.com/examples/transforms/matrix-calculator.html

The css for -30 degrees would be:

```
.rotate
{
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=0.86602540, M12=0.50000000, M21=-0.50000000, M22=0.86602540,sizingMethod='auto expand')";
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=0.86602540, M12=0.50000000, M21=-0.50000000, M22=0.86602540,sizingMethod='auto expand');
  -moz-transform:  matrix(0.86602540, -0.50000000, 0.50000000, 0.86602540, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transform:  matrix(0.86602540, -0.50000000, 0.50000000, 0.86602540, 0, 0);
  -o-transform:  matrix(0.86602540, -0.50000000, 0.50000000, 0.86602540, 0, 0);
}
```

Test page example:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
    body {
      -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=0.86602540, M12=0.50000000, M21=-0.50000000, M22=0.86602540,sizingMethod='auto expand')";
      filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=0.86602540, M12=0.50000000, M21=-0.50000000, M22=0.86602540,sizingMethod='auto expand');
      -moz-transform:  matrix(0.86602540, -0.50000000, 0.50000000, 0.86602540, 0, 0);
      -webkit-transform:  matrix(0.86602540, -0.50000000, 0.50000000, 0.86602540, 0, 0);
      -o-transform:  matrix(0.86602540, -0.50000000, 0.50000000, 0.86602540, 0, 0);
    }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Testing</p>
    <p><a href="http://www.boogdesign.com/examples/transforms/matrix-calculator.html">Matrix calculator here</a></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

For more information on calculating the matrix cooridinates see:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533014(VS.85).aspx
http://www.boogdesign.com/b2evo/index.php/2009/09/04/element-rotation-ie-matrix-filter?blog=2

Comment: Thanks for the cross browser code, this is much more than I expected!

Comment: @Joel, and you come from behind for the win :) I wonder, could you have just used the `ms` and opera stuff, and then gone with the simpler `-webkit-transform: rotate` and `-moz-transform: rotate` or is there a benefit to doing it this way?

Comment: @Doug, your suggestion set me looking for this, before that I didn't know you could rotate an element with plain css. Certainly the `rotate` could be used instead of `matrix` on Mozilla and Webkit, however, IE has a different origin than all the others, so to make it pixel perfect may require manipulating `-moz-transform-origin`.

Comment: @Joel right on man, like I said, awesome link. Will be using for sure. I have used the less cross browser solution for tipping photos a bit here and there, so this will make it way better. Thanks!

Comment: @Doug, the only good reason I could think of where you might want to use the matrix rotation method in all browsers was if you wanted consistent syntax across all the browsers, if perhaps you wanted to adjust the M values with Javascript.  BTW -o-transform: rotate(30deg) will work in Opera 10.50.

Answer (score 30):

Hey Adam, this will handle it for newer versions of Firefox and Safari:

```
body {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-30deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-30deg);
}
```

For Internet Explorer you could look into something like [Transformie](http://paulbakaus.com/2008/08/16/bringing-css-transform-to-internet-explorer/), or read the documentation for the [matrix filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533014(VS.85).aspx) for IE.

Comment: +1... Try this in Firebug: `document.body.style.MozTransform = 'rotate(-30deg)';` (instant gratification)

Comment: I don't think that I can describe how happy this makes me.  I am going to browse all my websites at a 30 degree angle from now on.

Comment: @Tchalvak Take this knowledge and use it to rotate a photo about 2 degrees, or a few sentences to look like a post-it note. :)

Comment: Curiously - what about chrome? does that support -moz or -webkit functions?

Comment: @viksit: chrome runs on a webkit rendering engine.

Comment: @viksit Chrome uses the `-webkit` command. For a silly example, here is my home page rotated 10 degrees (in FF and Chrome/Safari): http://pixelgraphics.us/test/rotate.html

Comment: You should add '-o-transform: rotate(-30deg)' and 'transform: rotate(-30deg)' too.

Comment: I like the simpler degree property in your answer, but unfortunately have to choose the cross-browser version, even though it's a bit more complex for the newbie.

Comment: @Adam, no problem! If I knew about that matrix generator first, it would have been in my answer... As it was: "read the documentation" == "I have no clue, but I know this is what you use" LOL. Have fun on April 1.

Answer (score 2):

To rotate the entire webpage you can use jQuery Transit and do something like this:

```
$("body").transition({rotate: "30deg"}, 6000);
```

Or if you want it to be immediately static you can do this:

```
$("body").css({rotate: "30deg"});
```

### [JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CayNE/)

Answer (score 1):

You can find an svg solution here:

> http://simulacrum.dorm.duke.edu/allyourgoogle.svg

And this is the same in pure css (at this time only works in webkit-based browsers though):

> http://a.qoid.us/google.html

Answer (score 1):

You can add transformations to HTML using SVG and a `<foreignObject>`

```
<svg xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"> 
  <g transform="translate(300, 0) rotate(20)"> 
    <foreignObject x="10" y="10" width="800" height="800"> 
      <body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
        <iframe src="http://stackoverflow.com" style="width:700px;height:700px"></iframe> 
      </body> 
    </foreignObject> 
  </g> 
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script language="JavaScript1.2">

var howOften = 5; //number often in seconds to rotate
var current = 0; //start the counter at 0
var ns6 = document.getElementById&&!document.all; //detect netscape 6

// place your images, text, etc in the array elements here
var items = new Array();
    items[0]="<a href='link.htm' ><img alt='image0 (9K)' src=' /Images/image0.jpg' height='300' width='300' border='0' /></a>"; //a linked image
    items[1]="<a href='link.htm'><img alt='image1 (9K)' src='/Images/image1.jpg' height='300' width='300' border='0' /></a>"; //a linked image
    items[2]="<a href='link.htm'><img alt='image2 (9K)' src='/Images/image2.jpg' height='300' width='300' border='0' /></a>"; //a linked image
   items[3]="<a href='link.htm'><img alt='image3 (9K)' src='/Images/image3.jpg' height='300' width='300' border='0' /></a>"; //a linked image
    items[4]="<a href='link.htm'><img alt='image4 (9K)' src='/Images/image4.jpg' height='300' width='300' border='0' /></a>"; //a linked image
    items[5]="<a href='link.htm'><img alt='image5 (18K)' src='/Images/image5.jpg' height='300' width='300' border='0' /></a>"; //a linked image
function rotater() {
    document.getElementById("placeholder").innerHTML = items[current];
    current = (current==items.length-1) ? 0 : current + 1;
    setTimeout("rotater()",howOften*1000);
}

function rotater() {
    if(document.layers) {
        document.placeholderlayer.document.write(items[current]);
        document.placeholderlayer.document.close();
    }
    if(ns6)document.getElementById("placeholderdiv").innerHTML=items[current]
        if(document.all)
            placeholderdiv.innerHTML=items[current];

    current = (current==items.length-1) ? 0 : current + 1; //increment or reset
    setTimeout("rotater()",howOften*1000);
}
window.onload=rotater;
//-->
</script>
```

At first glance, this code can appear intimidating. However, all you have to do is update the path to the image files and fill in the URLs for the links. Of course, you should also update the height and width attributes to fit your site.

If you only want four images to rotate, then simply delete one of the item rows. If you want to add one, then copy and paste and update items[5] to items[6] and so on.

You've now laid the ground work for adding this image rotator to your site. But there is one more step you need to do for your images to appear on the page. Figure out where you want the images to appear on the page and copy in:

```
<layer id="placeholderlayer"></layer><div id="placeholderdiv"></div>
```